# How to get attribute value from table row on click

Tags: jquery

I have a *TABLE* which is empty. I have an array called *menu* which contains a list of some products.
The code below iterates *menu* and creates rows in the table as many as there is products in the *menu* array.

To identify products in rows, -the best approache I could think of, was to use attribute; data-ID="" to store id of the product which is inserted in the row.

```
    var id=[];
$(document).ready(function addMenuToTable() {
    for ( var i in menu) {
        $('#menutable').append('<tr class ="product" role="button" data-id=""><td class"num">'+menu[i].num+'</td><td class="td-width"><span><b>'+menu[i].name+' </b></span><br>'+menu[i].ingred+'</td><td>'+menu[i].price+'</td></tr>');
        $('#menutable tr').attr('data-id', menu[i].id);
        id.push( $('#menutable tr').attr('data-id'));
    }
    console.log(id);
});
```

Now on click on any row, I want to retrieve the id of that certain product.

```
    $(document).on('click','tr', function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    console.log(id);
});
```

But when I test it with console.log, I only get the last product id, no matter what row I click on. Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

Comment: try var id = $(this).attr('data-ID');

Comment: Does not work, even with $(this). Still same problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**[Data Attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) should be lower case**. Change it to `data-id`.

Since you're looking for the value of a data attribute you can use jQuery's [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) to get the value, and use `$(this)` to get the jQuery item that was clicked:

```
var id = $(this).data('id');
```

**EG:**

```js
var menu = [];
menu.push({id:"1",num:1,name:"one",ingred:"uno",price:"1.11"});
menu.push({id:"2",num:2,name:"two",ingred:"dos",price:"2.22"});

$(function(){//on document ready...
  
    (function addMenuToTable(){
        for (var i in menu){
            $('#menutable').append('<tr data-id="'+menu[i].id+'" class="product" role="button" data-ID=""><td class"num">'+menu[i].num+'</td><td class="td-width"><span><b>'+menu[i].name+' </b></span><br>'+menu[i].ingred+'</td><td>'+menu[i].price+'</td></tr>');
        }
    })();//IIFE
  
    //listen for clicks
    $('#menutable').on('click','tr', function(){
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        alert(id);
    });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="menutable"></table>
```

Comment: already tried that, does not work. Still get only the last inserted id

Comment: My demo snippet works for me. What is it about your implementation that's different? Perhaps there's a problem with `menu[]` data itself?

Answer (score 1):

Add id in html when you are append instead of doing in next statement. Make this id lower case as well.

```
for ( var i in menu) {
    $('#menutable').append('<tr class ="product" role="button" data-id="' + menu[i].id +' "><td class"num">'+menu[i].num+'</td><td class="td-width"><span><b>'+menu[i].name+' </b></span><br>'+menu[i].ingred+'</td><td>'+menu[i].price+'</td></tr>');      
    id.push( menu[i].id);
}
```

Delegate click event with table instead of document.

```
$('#menutable').on('click','tr', function() {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    console.log(id);
});
```

Comment: Does not work, even with $(this). Still same problem.

Answer (score 1):

The data attribute name should not contain any uppercase letters. So first change **data-ID** to **data-id** and then get it using `$(this).data("id")`

Comment: That's because $('#menutable tr') refers always to the same element

Answer (score 1):

My proposal is:

```js
var menu=[{id: 1, num: '1', name: 'prod1', ingred: '', price: 10}, {id: 2, num: '2', name: 'prod2', ingred: '', price: 20}, {id: 3, num: '3', name: 'prod3', ingred: '', 'price': 30}];
var id = [];
$(function () {
  for ( var i in menu) {
    $('#menutable').append('<tr class ="product" role="button" data-id="' + menu[i].id + '"><td class"num">'+menu[i].num+'</td><td class="td-width"><span><b>'+menu[i].name+' </b></span><br>'+menu[i].ingred+'</td><td>'+menu[i].price+'</td></tr>')
    id.push(menu[i].id);
  }
  $('#log').append('<p>' + id + '</p>');
});


$(document).on('click','tr', function() {
  var id = $(this).data('id');
  $('#log').append('<p>' + id + '</p>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>

<table id="menutable"></table>
<div id="log"></div>
```